# Find my saved answer

Tags: support

Two days back a new user asked a good question. I began to answer it but it felt that I would not be able to complete my response in that sitting. So I left my answer incomplete (as I know SO keeps that answer and I can access my same incomplete answer even from another device) planning to answer it later that day.

Now, it's been two days and I am finally free but unfortunately I have lost that question.

Is there any way I can find that question (I don't remember all of its tags)? Or can I find my saved and incomplete answers?

Comment: Do you have a link to it in your browser history?  There may be a chance that it's been deleted.

Comment: This may help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Makoto in comments to the question, the only way to find it out is to check your browser history. At least as of now I could find no way to locate a draft of my unfinished answers.